# Java v7 doesn't work with oracle forms 10g?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g

I don't know if my version of Oracle Developer 10g R2 (Forms and Reports) works with the newest version of Java, because when I upgrade since version 1.6.014 to 1.7.067 the pluggin on my browser doesn't work and I can't to deploy oracle forms aplicattions locally.

anybody works with Java v7 and Forms 10g?

My actual environment:
- Windows 7 Pro x64
- Core i5 2.60 GHZ
- 8 GB Ram
- JRE 1.6.0_14
- Forms[x32] 10.1.2.0.2

thanks for any help.

Comment: What does "the pluggin on my browser doesn't work" exactly mean? What do you expect do happen? Which error do you see?

Comment: After I upgrade the java version, the browser's pluggin show me like is not installed and re-direct the page to Java download page. If I return the java version to 1.6.0_14 the pluggin works and execute the form without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 does work with Oracle Developer 10g according to Steven Chan whom blogs about Oracle E-Business Suite technology.  If you look at the Oracle support note 437878.1, 
[Upgrading OracleAS 10g Forms and Reports in Oracle E-Business Suite Release 12](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&id=437878.1), it will describe the necessary set-ups and configuration.

His [entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/stevenChan/entry/jre_7_certified_with_oracle) on Java 7 and Oracle Applications is pretty thorough.

Comment: Do you know which is the latest Java version supported by Oracle Forms 10g?

Comment: @dmak2709 I am somewhat removed from working at an EBS shop now. I think 8 is supported, but please review appropriate certification matrix on MOS.

Comment: I really struggle to find a valuable resource, where I can find it out maybe from the Oracle official site?